# Is there RailsPanel for nodejs/expressjs?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js, express, debugging, google-chrome-extension

Is there a tool similar to RailsPanel for expressjs (or nodejs in general)? I'd like to see as much as possible about nodejs routes in Google Chrome extension.

Comment: Can you add any details like: code used, error problem encountered? [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Show the community what you have tried.

Comment: There is no problem encounter or code used. I've tried looking for something like RailsPanel for nodejs/express, but found nothing. That's why I ask